# How Do I check If a variable is in an array I made

Tags: c++

I am trying to check if my inputted variable is in an array.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

int Year;
int Elem_School [] =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int Mid_School[] = { 6, 7, 8 };
int High_School[] = { 9, 10, 11, 12 };

std::cout << " Please enter your School Year: " ;
std::cin >> Year;

for (const auto& val : Elem_School) {
    std::cout << "Your are in elementry school" << std::endl;
}

for (const auto& val : Mid_School) {
    std::cout << "You are in middle school" << std::endl;
}

for (const auto& val : High_School) {
    std::cout << "You are in high school" << std::endl;
}
}
```

Thank you in advance. oh and im new to all of this so if you wouldn't mind could you explain what to do and why its working and stuff. It prints the output of all of them How do I stop this.

Comment: There are many ways, but how about starting with a simple for loop?

Comment: ok so how do I make that work I know the set up for the for loop     for ( init; condition; increment ) {} but what would I do for each.  (i'm sorry for not understanding)

Comment: `std::find(std::begin(Elem_School), std::end(Elem_School), Year) != std::end(Elem_School)` [Documentation for `std:find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

Comment: @CodeVapor you could use a [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead: Eg: `for (const auto & val:Elem_School)`.

Comment: @user4581301 when I used That  for loop it output                                                                     Please enter your School Year: 3
Your are in elementary school (x5)
You are in middle school (x3)
You are in high school (x4)                                                                                               was I supposed to do something else  after to make it only print if it was in the array.oh and I filled in the question so you could see what I ment

Comment: You need to test `val` against `Year` and ONLY print if they match. It's OK to be new to something, but you owe it to yourself to think what you are doing through. Come up with a plan. How would you, with a piece of paper and a pencil, figure out what school a student goes to? The exact same logic will work in a computer program. It might not be optimal, but it's always enough to get you started.

Comment: This is a problem I'd solve with one array of strings. array elements from 1 to 5 would contain "elementary school". 6 through 8 would contain "middle school". 9-12 contain "high school". That makes the program `std::cout << "Your are in " << shool_array[Year] << std::endl;` Although to protect the program from typos and jerks, I'd check `Year` to make sure the user typed in 1 to 12.

Answer (score 0):

Before you use some higher level C++ language stuff, you should simple apply the

[if statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

to check if the given school year is part of one of your defined arrays.

Please try this code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

int Year;
int Elem_School [] =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int Mid_School[] = { 6, 7, 8 };
int High_School[] = { 9, 10, 11, 12 };

std::cout << " Please enter your School Year: " ;
std::cin >> Year;

for (const auto& val : Elem_School) {
    if (val == Year)
        std::cout << "Your are in elementary school" << std::endl;
}

for (const auto& val : Mid_School) {
    if (val == Year)
        std::cout << "You are in middle school" << std::endl;
}

for (const auto& val : High_School) {
    if (val == Year)
        std::cout << "You are in high school" << std::endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Please note that I've added `return 0` at the end of your `main` function, as it isn't `void` and the number `0` tells the invoker of your program that all was running as expected.

Hope it helps?